# How to merge 2 channel of optical flow grayscale JPG images into one RGB image in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opticalflow

I'm making a RGB image from the given 2 grayscale jpg images, which is for x, y channel in optical flow respectively.

[sample input images and my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T1dI.jpg)

```
def optical_flow(one, two, w, h):
    """
    method taken from (https://chatbotslife.com/autonomous-vehicle-speed-estimation-from-dashboard-cam-ca96c24120e4)
    """
    one_g = cv2.cvtColor(one, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    two_g = cv2.cvtColor(two, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    hsv = np.zeros((w, h, 3))
    # set saturation
    hsv[:,:,1] = cv2.cvtColor(two, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)[:,:,1]
    # obtain dense optical flow paramters
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(one_g, two_g, flow=None,
                                        pyr_scale=0.5, levels=1, winsize=15,
                                        iterations=2,
                                        poly_n=5, poly_sigma=1.1, flags=0)
    # convert from cartesian to polar
    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
    # hue corresponds to direction
    hsv[:,:,0] = ang * (180/ np.pi / 2)
    # value corresponds to magnitude
    hsv[:,:,2] = cv2.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    # convert HSV to int32's
    hsv = np.asarray(hsv, dtype= np.float32)
    rgb_flow = cv2.cvtColor(hsv,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
    return rgb_flow 

imgu = cv2.imread('u.jpg')
imgv = cv2.imread('v.jpg')
img = optical_flow(one, two, w, h)

Image.fromarray(imgu, 'RGB').show() // top-left one in img
Image.fromarray(imgv, 'RGB').show() // top-right one in img
Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB').show()  // bottom-left one in img
```

I think the output image looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

Optical flow computes a motion vector field of two consequtive frames. In you case `one` and `two`. However, your input images u and v does not show consequtive frames. The problem here is that there is no relation between the images, i.e. no similar content. Cosequently your optical flow field `flow` will have some random like values.

When computing the color coded visualisation of your optical flow field. In your case the saturation channel is initialized not correctly:

```
# set saturation
hsv[:,:,1] = cv2.cvtColor(two, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)[:,:,1]
```

Set it to 255. More common solutation is to set the value channel to 255 and use the saturation channel to encode the magnitude.